# svn: local commits

Tags: svn, commit

Subversion: is it possible to commit local revisions without pushing them, and push them at a later date - or is the lack of this feature why it's called "centralized" ?

Comment: use Git. it has that feature

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is not possible to do local commits with Subversion.

This is because, as a centralized version control system, your local working copy does not have all the information the server has about past revisions, log entries, etc. which it would have had if it was a Distributed Version Control System (DVCS).

A subversion working copy contains a copy of all files as they were checked out so you can revert changed files without contacting the server.

If you really want to do local commits you should have a look at [SVK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVK), which is built on top of Subversion and provides DVCS like features.

Comment: Do you have experience with SVK? I've used it a bit and it seemed alright, but I don't have much faith in smooth svn uses any more.  I'd imagine anything built on top of it would be just as wobbly.

Comment: @jskulski: I have no experience with SVK, but their "antiFUD" page address your question: http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/SVKAntiFUD

Comment: This answer is a little misleading. It is not because SVN is centralized that local commits are not possible. It is simply an omitted implementation detail. Treating local commits as a queue of changesets that can get batch-pushed to the repo is technically feasible (svk shows this)-- it would just change the UX to the point where SVN becomes more "difficult" to use (using the standard workflow). SVN chooses to optimize on ease of use, not functionality; but it could be hacked into Subversion without breaking anything.

Comment: What if you create a local server in your computer so that you can commit to it, and then when you are ready to commit to the original repository, then you just commit the regular way.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 35):

Much of the above has become somewhat obsolete, and since this question comes up as a hit in a google search for "svn local commit" here's an update:

Consider using the package "git-svn" (along with "git-gui" if you don't know git) to make local commits both possible and easy, with full remote SVN integration.  A decent overview/tutorial/use-case is [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client#Git-and-Subversion).  I've just started using this process with Sourceforge projects, so I can't yet report any problems.  Be sure to get the Authors file right!

EDIT: Updated link. Thanks, hdl!

Comment: +1 - for noting redundancy. I think I even read somewhere that SVN will be introducing local commits.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: Archive.org has a copy of the webpage: https://web.archive.org/web/20130924234957/http://utsl.gen.nz/talks/git-svn/intro.html

Comment: Link has been moved to http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client#Git-and-Subversion

Comment: Mercurial and Bazaar can both work with SVN repositories as well, actually. So look into those if you don't enjoy git's interface.

Comment: Also since you mentioned git-gui, if you're on Windows check out TortoiseGit (or TortoiseHg if you choose that route).

Answer (score 5):

You could do such a thing so if you interface the SVN Server with a GIT or Mercurial Bridge. Since GIT and Mercurial are able to do local Commits you could then use them like that. Maybe check out git-svn or something similiar (I remember there being a bazaar-svn but not sure).

Comment: A variant of this is to 'git init' in an SVN working copy, make your local commits offline. Later, you commit the final state (or even intermediate ones) to SVN. After this you could also delete the .git directory.

This would mean your working copy stays a SVN working copy, not a git-repo.

Answer (score 3):

That is why it is called centralized. You could try using a repo inside a repo. One is local and the other is remote. You then commit the entire inner repository to the remote.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, no.

I would **strongly** recommend trying to use anything remotely janky with svn.

I haven't used SVK enough to recommend against it, it seemed nice enough. However I am skeptical of using anything built on top of SVN for an entire project without anything breaking. I have use SVN enough to know that even regular work cycles can toast it if you're not careful.

We use SVN at work. I have been using bzr and bzr-svn to do all my interaction with and it works **wonderfully**. My workflow is something like:

`$ bzr branch file:///var/svn/project ~/project`

*(hack, hack, hack)*

`$ bzr commit -m "commit log"`
(repeat)

when I'm ready

`$ bzr push`

Yes, instead of updating you have `$ bzr merge` and commit change (possibly shelving what you are working on) but local commits are a **very** nice thing, and *shelving* is too (shelving is like *revert* with a *save*)

I think git handles this as well. I've heard it is not as complete as bzr-svn, but I can not corroborate that.

But using a DVCS with a svn repository is a good way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Further to BobC's answer, for mercurial you would use `hgsubversion`.

Answer (score 1):

No! git however can do this, and you can use git-svn to
keep in sync with the original repository.

Answer (score 1):

To get the best of both worlds, [SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/) was built on top of Subversion, but maintaining local state so you can do local commits...