# svn - how to save commits when server is unavailable

Tags: svn

Assume svn server is not available for couple of days (for example you are in place with no internet connection).

I can keep working and commit when svn is back but this is not convenient because all my changes will go to only one revision.

Instead I want to "checkpoint" revisions locally and when svn is back I want to commit bunch of revisions.

In other words - different bug fixes should go to different revisions.

I understand I can create local svn server and then synchronize servers. But can I do what I want to do without creating extra svn server?

Comment: might be intresting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081058/svn-local-commits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've already rejected the local-svn repos option.... perhaps you should look into git?  And git-svn?

Answer (score 1):

As Jake Feasel mentioned, git is probably the best way to go. If that's not an option you could create patches (diffs) each time you want to have a checkpoint. When the repository is available again, make a clean checkout, patch, commit, patch, commit &c.

Comment: with patches during development I will not be able to see changes between two revisions....

Comment: Huh, why not? Your patches *are* the changes between the (future) revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Local SVN-server (and switch command) or DVCS - you haven't more than these two options.

Contrary to git-boys, I suggest to use Mercurial and hgsubversion as more transparent and brain-powered bridge to Subversion