# Getting SVN updates from repos1 and do commit into repos2

Tags: git, svn, commit

I am accessing a SVN repository and I issue update command regularly to keep my local copy up to date with the latest changes in that repository. I am also doing modifications, and creating new files in the local copy on my computer.

I can not commit my own changes to the repos since I am not allowed to. Is there any way that I can keep track of my own changes and commit them in a separate repository? (like my own repository in github).

Comment: git and svn can coexist - you can create your own local git repo. Any time you update from svn, just commit whatever it did in your git. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081058/svn-local-commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git svn is a simple conduit for changesets between Subversion and git. It provides a bidirectional flow of changes between a Subversion and a git repository.

Use this command to pull

```
!git-svn fetch && git-svn rebase
```

and then have a tracking branch on git say 'master' which tracks the 'git-svn' " svn branch".

then you can use regular git commands to track changes in master branch with git.

[This documentation link](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html)  should help you with the setup.